# Generate a Crystal Reports TTX file from an ADODB.Recordset

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports, recordset

Is there an API call for Crystal Reports 8.5 that will generate a TTX schema file from a VB6 ADODB.Recordset at runtime, much in the same way you can generate an XSD from a DataSet in .NET? I could roll my own, and I think I probably will have to, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel because I missed something obvious.

Comment: Off topic but doesn't everyone just get this bad taste when they see the words Crystal Reports ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not. But a TTX file is a pretty simple format - just field name, type, length. You can loop through the Recordset's Field collection to create a string of the info required, and save it to a TTX file. I'm afraid I don't have Crystal or VB6 to hand so I can't give exact details, but something like this pseudocode :

```
Dim strTTX as String
Dim intI as Integer
With rst
    For intI = 0 to .Fields.Count - 1
        With .Fields(intI)
            strTTX = .Name & vbTab & FieldTypeDesc(.Type)
            If .Type = adChar Then
                strTTX = strTTX & vbtab & .Length
            End
            strTTX = strTTX & vbCrLf
        End With
    Next
End With
strTTX = Left$(strTTX, Len(strTTX) - 1) 'remove trailing vbCrLf
```

then add code to save that string as a TTX somewhere.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I figured I would wind up having to do; thanks.